How to convert a template type into a new type
In the following template function f(), I want to convert the template type T to type TD.
For example, when T=A, the conversion results in type AD.
For example, when T=B, the conversion results in type BD.
A,AD,B,BD are some C++ classes.
#include <iostream>

#define CONN(T, data) new T##D(data)

class A {
 private:
  int m_data;

 public:
  A(int data) : m_data(data) {}
  ~A() {}
  void print() { std::cout << "A.data = " << m_data << std::endl; }
};

class AD {
 private:
  int m_data;

 public:
  AD(int data) : m_data(data) {}
  ~AD() {}
  void print() { std::cout << "AD.data = " << m_data << std::endl; }
};

class B {
 private:
  int m_data;

 public:
  B(int data) : m_data(data) {}
  ~B() {}
  void print() { std::cout << "B.data = " << m_data << std::endl; }
};

class BD {
 private:
  int m_data;

 public:
  BD(int data) : m_data(data) {}
  ~BD() {}
  void print() { std::cout << "BD.data = " << m_data << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
void f() {
  auto ad = CONN(A, 100); // OK
  ad->print();
  auto bd = CONN(T, 100); // FAIL
  bd->print();
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  f<B>();
  return 0;
}

$ g++ 18.cpp -o t
18.cpp: In function 'void f()':
18.cpp:49:18: error: expected type-specifier before 'TD'
   49 |   auto bd = CONN(T, 100);
      |                  ^
18.cpp:3:27: note: in definition of macro 'CONN'
    3 | #define CONN(T, data) new T##D(data)
      |                           ^

When using macro function conversion, if the macro parameter is a specific type (e.g., A), the conversion can succeed (A-->AD). If the macro parameter is a template type (e.g., T), the conversion fails (T-->TD).
But I don't have the specific class TD.
I know that macro replacement is in the preprocessing stage, and the specific type of the template parameter cannot be known until the compile time. Therefore, the latter conversion will fail.
In the template parameter, is it possible to convert one type into another new type?

Avoid using macros.

Which of the classes are under your control? You could move e.g AD to be a member class of A with a fixed name (so AD becomes A::foo and BD becomes B::foo).

There appears to be no relation, other than the class name, between A and AD. And there aren't that many points in C++ where the class name really matters ; usually only the actual type matters. But where the name matters, it has to be an exact match. The difference between A and AD is the same as A to BD - not equal

Also, there's a pretty pointless new in the example, causing a memory leak. This gives the overall impression that this codebase needs proper fixing, not a band-aid.

It's likely that AD really should be a nested class A::D. In that case, you don't need a macro at all, and T::D just needs a typename T::D.

@HolyBlackCat Yes, AD to be a member class of A is a solution. Something like:
class A{  using Type = AD; };
I have many class pairs, e.g., A and AD, B and BD, C and CD, etc. So I need a easy way to get class XD from class X (X can be A, B, C, ...).

@MSalters A nested class A::D is something like class A{ class D{}; };? This is also a solution. But I need to define two classes separately. Therefore, I need a way to convert class A to class AD. Also convert class X to class XD (X can be A, B, C, ...).

@allbluelai: It seems (also from your comment on Caleth's answer) that you're confused by the difference between a type and the name of a type. In particular, a type can have multiple names. In your template, the template parameter X refers to the type A, but the parameter is still named X. Your imagined XD confused an operation on the name (append D to X) and an operation on the type (A ->AD).

You can write a trait.
template <typename>
struct conn;

template <>
struct conn<A> {
    using type = AD;
};

template <>
struct conn<B> {
    using type = BD;
};

template <typename T>
using conn_t = typename conn<T>::type;

Which you can then use
template <typename T>
void f() {
  conn_t<A> ad(100); // OK
  ad.print();
  conn_t<T> bd(100); // OK
  bd.print();
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  f<B>();
  return 0;
}

See it on coliru

Thanks for your solutions.
The trait work fine.
However, there are many class pairs, such as A and AD, B and BD, C and CD, etc.
I cannot define so many traits like conn and conn.

@allbluelai why not? They don't need to all be in the same file, e.g. you can follow the definition of AD with the conn<A> specialisation
